# Nuget PM crashes VS 2019

Tags: crash, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Using the latest VS update 16.7.4 but happened also on .3 and .2.  Working on a Xamarin.Forms project when I first started noticing it, but now it happens on any project when I try to go to the menu and click [Manage Nuget Packages for the Solution].

NPM shows up fine.  If I stay on the installed or updates tab it works fine.  But when I click the BROWSE tab it shows a list of the latest searches, and then after about 3 seconds the cursor pops up, then vs becomes un responsive and it crashes.

I don't know much about looking at the vs logs to find out what is going on.  I happens on every project now, so I don't think removing the .vs or .obj folders have anything to do with it, although I tried it on the Xamarin Project to no avail.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: If I set the selector on the nuget form to offline packages it doesn't have a problem.  As soon as I pick nuget.org (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json), the behavior reappears.  But I can connect using the browser to the json file and it works fine.

Comment: Hi Carlos, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Nuget PM crashes VS 2019

**1) First**, disable any other VS installed Extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** to check whether a vs extension caused that.

**2)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

**3)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset All VS Settings**

**4)** close VS Instance, delete the global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` then reopen VS to regenerate that file.

**5)** check under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Sources**

try to use `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/` or `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/` as `nuget.org` source.

**Also**, uncheck other package source and only remain the nuget.org package source.

[image]

**6)** delete `bin` and `obj` folder of the project to do a clean step. Also, you can try to install one package on the new project to test whether the issue happens again.

**7)** try to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and it works as the final step.